# What's the name of the "Candy Crush" style of game?

Tags: game-design

I'm currently creating an engine trying to auto-play games with a chess board, and I'm writing a report about it now.

However, I found it hard to properly describe it -- for the games like Candy Crush, which has a game board, filled with "candies," and a few rules.. is there a formal classification for it?

Is "board-game" a proper name? What about "rectangle-tile game", or "chessboard-based game?"

Comment: Most of those types of games are called Puzzle Games. But that's maybe to general for what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Games like Candy Crush are called "Match-three" games, and generally, it and games like it are [tile-based games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_game), or board games, or even tile-based board games.